# Can't get Div to affect Divs below it

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that's been giving me quite some trouble.  What I'm trying to do is make the menu links, when clicked, reveal a drop down secondary division.  However, it's acting as if the menu being revealed is floating and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's the ideal design I want:
http://jsfiddle.net/WeL6j/7/

- Notice how the grey division is affected and slides down as well.

I'd like the same thing to happen with the divs that hold 01, 02, etc and the one with the green 01.  Basically all the content below the menu.  I've posted a fiddle of my code just to give an idea of what it's doing and so you can edit it in real time.  I haven't created any fallback code for it, so it's only really viewable in chrome. (sorry)  It's also going to be messy as I've been moving things around trying to get it to work properly.  Anyways, here's what I have so far.

-removed-

Thanks in advance for the help, Brian.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ETaqa/63/

BTW, you should really format the nesting.  It was confusing figuring out the div levels.

Comment: Yeah, like I said.  Still toying with it, so it's messy.  Sorry.  That's doing the same thing I posted, but with a red background.  I want the divisions below the menu that reveals to slide down with the menu, and back up when it hides.  Thanks for taking a look at it, Brian.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  I couldn't even get your code working on the fiddle or your site.  I changed it so that when you click on the `011` link, a red div slides down underneath `011` and `02 to 07` are moved down.  That's how it's working for me.  Does it not work for you?

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't see that's what you did.  Nice, but what I was going for was the menu links at the top.  Click Winter Weather etc and watch the drop down.  It just drops and the content below stays in place.  I'd like the content below to move down like the 02 does under 011

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ETaqa/63/ You have too many redundant divs.  The row div for example is useless.  And you should use some more descriptive names instead of `col1, col2, col3, ...`

Comment: Yeah, I haven't organized my code too much yet.  I'm going to do it when I add the fallback support.  I started this not long ago.  The posts are being pulled from a default wordpress I set up in january.  I literally got it working the second you posted that.  Thank you so much for taking a look at it.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can define some properties in you css as like this

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    top: -7px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: If you have the time, would you mind showing me in fiddle how to achieve the effect I'm looking for?  I feel as if I've tried everything I can think of.  It was working once and I changed code around to fix a second problem thinking I knew how to get it back, and I can't.  Thanks in advance, Brian.